# Android paired to a RFCOMM device can not connect

Tags: android, bluetooth, connection, rfcomm

At first I have to say, that I'm a beginner on android. I'm working on an App, which should connect to a measuring instrument without any operating elements(no Buttons, no Display) over bluetooth and receive the measured data. Unfortunately I don't know much about the measure instrument and the manufacturer as well. Everything I know is, that I have to communicate over RFCOMM and when I am pairing with android I have to send the serial number as PIN (09000). 
This works so far. Andorid pairs with the device. When trying to connect, it first builds up the connection and seconds later it interrupts. I'm working with a Samsung Galaxy S3 and HTC Sensation.

Here you can find my complete Bluetooth connection class:

http://iukp.chefti.com/JAVA/AndroidBluetooth.java

Here is the logcat output for more reference:

```
    12-22 17:24:56.104: I/System.out(6079): ConnectThread()
    12-22 17:24:56.104: V/BluetoothSocket.cpp(6079): initSocketNative
    12-22 17:24:56.104: V/BluetoothSocket.cpp(6079): ...fd 51 created (RFCOMM, lm = 26)
    12-22 17:24:56.104: V/BluetoothSocket.cpp(6079): initSocketFromFdNative
    12-22 17:24:56.109: I/System.out(6079): ConnectThread() try succesfull
    12-22 17:24:56.114: I/System.out(6079): ConnectThread.run()
    12-22 17:24:56.114: I/System.out(6079): mmSocket.connect 0.1()
    12-22 17:24:56.124: D/BluetoothUtils(6079): isSocketAllowedBySecurityPolicy start :         device null
    12-22 17:24:57.109: V/BluetoothSocket.cpp(6079): connectNative
    12-22 17:24:57.174: V/BluetoothSocket.cpp(6079): ...connect(51, RFCOMM) = 0 (errno 115)
    12-22 17:24:57.179: I/System.out(6079): true
    12-22 17:24:57.184: I/System.out(6079): ConnectedThread()
    12-22 17:24:57.184: I/System.out(6079): socket.X tried
    12-22 17:24:57.184: I/System.out(6079): manageConnectedSocket()
    12-22 17:24:57.184: I/System.out(6079): run()
    12-22 17:24:57.184: I/System.out(6079): ConnectThread() try succesfull - run()
    12-22 17:24:57.184: I/System.out(6079): SON F BICHT
    12-22 17:24:57.184: I/Choreographer(6079): Skipped 67 frames!  The application may         be doing too much work on its main thread.
    12-22 17:24:58.189: D/dalvikvm(6079): GC_CONCURRENT freed 91K, 6% free 12469K/13191K, paused 21ms+4ms, total 76ms
    12-22 17:24:58.209: V/BluetoothSocket.cpp(6079): abortNative
    12-22 17:24:58.209: V/BluetoothSocket.cpp(6079): ...asocket_abort(51) complete
    12-22 17:24:58.209: V/BluetoothSocket.cpp(6079): destroyNative
    12-22 17:24:58.209: V/BluetoothSocket.cpp(6079): ...asocket_destroy(51) complete
```

Any hint or suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 3):

Since you asked this about six month ago I hope you already solved your problem but for others ending up here your problem might have something to do with this:

[Android Bluetooth SPP with Galaxy S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274210/android-bluetooth-spp-with-galaxy-s3)

Check out the answeres to that question.